# How to use rsync correctly to compare file hashes of two directories incl. subdirectories and interpret its output?

Tags: rsync, directory, remote, hashsum, file-comparison

To check equality of a local and a remote directory I want to compare the hashes of all the files and did:

```
$ rsync -avcn /home/me-here/thisss/ me@other.server:/home/me-there/thisss/ > diffs.txt
```

The `diffs.txt` then contains the following:

```
sending incremental file list
./
MAIN/
MAIN/1563410001/
MAIN/1563410002/
MAIN/1563410003/
MAIN/1563410016/
MAIN/1563410017/
MAIN/1563410018/
MAIN/9846540055/
MAIN/9846540059/
MAIN/9846540073/
MAIN/9846540090/
MAIN/7654330036/
MAIN/7654330038/
MAIN/7654330070/
thisss/
thisss/xyz/
thisss/Data/

sent 76,267 bytes  received 5,695 bytes  64.21 bytes/sec
total size is 14,706,824,172  speedup is 179,434.67 (DRY RUN)
```

Actually I think this looks good, therefore just two quick questions:

May I assume according to this output that all **hashes** are equal and nothing is corrupt? How would this output look like if there actually were some differences?

Comment: It's usually better to use `-i` in place of `-v` if you're planning to interpret the output. The output format for `-i` (`--itemize-change`) is described in the manual (and modifiable).  Note that `-a` (`--archive`) would also trigger transfer of meta data if e.g. a timestamp or permission etc. was different.

Comment: @Kusalananda The `-i` was a good tip giving the needed verbosity, thanks.